# POST request to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, post

I have this next code

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Nieuwe gebruiker | Sociale buurt</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="onzebuurt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function formulierValideren() {     
        if (document.getElementById('Username').value == '' || document.getElementById('Username').value == null)
        {
            alert ('Gebruikersnaam is verplicht.');
            document.getElementById('Username').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('Wachtwoord').value == '' || document.getElementById('Wachtwoord').value == null)
        {
            alert ('Wachtwoord is verplicht.');
            document.getElementById('Wachtwoord').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('Wachtwoord2').value == '' || document.getElementById('Wachtwoord2').value == null)
        {
            alert ('Bevestig wachtwoord.');
            document.getElementById('Wachtwoord2').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('Wachtwoord2').value != document.getElementById('Wachtwoord').value)
        {
            alert ('Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.');
            document.getElementById('Wachtwoord2').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#bevestig").click(function() {
                gebruikerToevoegen();
            });

            var msg = "Registratie succesvol. Klik op OK om u aan te melden op de site.";
            if(confirm(msg)){
            setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = "http://webs.hogent.be/kevinbaeyens/"})
            }
        }
        //end if
}//end function

function gebruikerToevoegen() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url);
request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status == 201){
        alert("everything OK!");
    } else {
        alert("you're wrong");
    }
};
}

</script>
</head>
<body class="body2">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div class="header1">
    <center>    
    Nieuwe gebruiker
    </center>
</div>
    <div id="formulier2">
        <form method="post" name="form" action="">
            <p class="labels"><center>Gebruikersnaam *</center></p><input id="Username" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" size="50">
            <p class="labels"><center>Wachtwoord *</center></p><input id="Wachtwoord" type="password" name="Wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord" size="50">
            <p class="labels"><center>Bevestig wachtwoord *</center></p><input id="Wachtwoord2" type="password" name="Bevestig wachtwoord" placeholder="Bevestig wachtwoord" size="50">
            <br />
            <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none"><center><img id="return" name="jsbutton" src="return.png" alt="Terug" /></center></a>
            <br />
            <center><input id="bevestig" type="image" src="Bevestig.png" width="200"  height="50" border="0" alt="SUBMIT!" onclick="formulierValideren()"></center>
            <br />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to send the data from #Username and #Wachtwoord to my MySQL database.
Please help me please, i'm stuck on this for almost a week now. i'll be so happy if anyone could help me! if i need to give more information, please ask me

Comment: You need to have something running on your server (PHP, ASP.NET, etc) that will accept the post request and pass it to MySQL.  You can't post directly to MySQL without some intermediate layer.

Answer (score 0):

first I thought you were looking for a client side solution (which woul be a very bad idea anyway). Jason is right. But if you want something kind of automatic, have a look to smarty php. Though, first you have to learn some basic stuff and a watch very clear example you could find in this video tuto: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvGb5Z0yMFY

Comment: thanks for the help, very useful! The only problem is that I have to do this for a project and we can't use PHP, so I think i have to solve this problem by using JQuery or something else? the only question is how?

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you using a framework (seems jQuery) and dooing something like this

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

You may have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

2) It would recommend, to use e.preventDefault instead of returning *false* on validation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

3) What are you doing in your "action"? Or: where is your *url* pointing to?
as mentioned before: you need some kind of "endpoint" on the serverside:

http://www.springsource.org/

http://www.asp.net/

http://rubyonrails.org/

https://www.djangoproject.com/

http://framework.zend.com/

http://www.catalystframework.org/

http://www.seaside.st/

or whatever